# Issue: Set Alarm Based on UnixTimestamp

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, unix-timestamp

I am trying to set the alarm based on UnixTimestamp, but always the application send alarm before the time i set it , e.g i set alarm on 1563551362 , now the problem is i received the alarm not on 1563551362 but i got the alarm before the time i set it, any one can help?

I have tried the following code to set the alarm :

```
private void setNotificationAlarm(long unixTimeStamp){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), broadcastReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, broadcastReciever, pendingIntent);

}
```

Comment: Just guessing (since it isn’t clear from the question), are you confusing milliseconds and seconds since the epoch? If the method you are calling expects milliseconds and you pass 1563551362 (seconds), it will be understood as January 19, 1970 at 02:19:11.362 UTC. Which would probably cause the alarm to fire immediately.

Answer (score 0):

From the [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

> Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is
>   inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and
>   battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need
>   strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long,
>   android.app.PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long,
>   android.app.PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is
>   earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in
>   which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

So you could use:

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, unixTimeStamp, pendingIntent);
```

But the API warns that:

> only alarms for which there is a strong demand for exact-time delivery
>   (such as an alarm clock ringing at the requested time) should be
>   scheduled as exact. Applications are strongly discouraged from using
>   exact alarms unnecessarily as they reduce the OS's ability to minimize
>   battery use